# Creating a dictionary without using counter

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary, counter

`INFO` is a `list` which I'm sorting using a `Counter` and would like the output to be in the form of a dictionary. However, I'm getting characters that aren't necessary:

```
wanted_dict = collections.Counter(INFO)
>>> Counter({'BLA': 102, 'BLABLA': 96, 'BLABLABLA': 96...})
```

The unnecessary characters being:

```
Counter
(
)
```

Is there a way to output the following instead?

```
>>> {'BLA': 102, 'BLABLA': 96, 'BLABLABLA': 96...}
```

Comment: `dict(wanted_dict)`? You don't have *"unnecessary characters"*, you have the wrong type of object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it in a `dict` call.

```
>>> dict(Counter({'BLA': 102, 'BLABLA': 96, 'BLABLABLA': 96}))
{'BLABLABLA': 96, 'BLABLA': 96, 'BLA': 102}
```

You can turn most special `collections` dictionary objects into normal dictionaries with this method.